# UVC MJPEG stream - Is it possible to extract jpeg images from a USB UVC stream?

Tags: stm32, microcontroller, mjpeg, uvc

I am using a STM32 microcontroller code base that someone wrote to read UVC data from an HDMI to USB interface. I'm able to collect image data setting it to MJPEG format but am having trouble getting valid images.
https://github.com/iliasam/STM32_HOST_UVC_Camera

My thought was that you should be able to collect raw MJPEG data from the device and splice out the MJPEG data (starting at FF D8, ending at FF D9, JPEG start/end addresses) then that would be a single still image from the device. It seems to somewhat work but the image doesn't look completely correct. I see tinges of valid data, most of it looks to be garbage.

Is this the correct approach? Or, is there something specific that you need to do to raw MJPEG data received from UVC drivers?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I had some pointer mistakes in data collection.

The answer is yes, you are able to splice out FF D8 to FF D9 and pick raw image data out, then put this into a binary file and rename to .jpg and it will work.